# Non-mvc applications asks for WebPages.Razor assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-8.1

I have solution with several projects in it. One of the projects is an MVC application. In this solution there is also WCF project, Web Forms project  and several class libraries.

The interesting thing that WCF services and Web Forms hasn't in references assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor. They compile well, but when i run WCF service or site i have an error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The same is for Web Forms.
When i copy this assembly to bin folder service and web forms sirte starts fine.
Any ideas why it can happens?

**UPDATE: I have Windows 8.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your references, 
you might be referencing a project from your WCF project that relies on 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' internally.

For example a common project with domain objects. When this common project exposes Razor elements, then all referencing projects (like your WCF/ form project) would require Razor as well.

Comment: No, looks like wcf service not referenced to my MVC app.

Comment: WCF on its own, does not require Razor, and you state that the WCF project has no direct reference to MVC (which does reference razor). There should be a reference chain going from your WCF project to your MVC project. maybe not directly but via a third(or even fourth)  project:  [WCF] -> [SomeLAYERProject] -> [MVC] -> [Razor]